# How to collect command line arguments in group using python argparse api?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a script that uses `argparse` to process command line arguments. The script accepts multiple options and all options accepts a list of strings as arguments. As shown below:

```
cmd.py -s [arg ...] -t [arg ...] -p [arg ...]
```

This implementations is done and working well. Now, user wants to combine the arguments to each option in a group. As such, if command is executed as:

```
cmd.py -s -t -p arg1 arg2 arg3
```

`ArgumentParser` should pass this argument list `[arg1 arg2 arg3]` to all supplied options and should have same effect as if command is executed as below

```
cmd.py -s arg1 arg2 arg3 -t arg1 arg2 arg3 -p arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Is this possible to to create a `ArgumentParser` in such a way?

Comment: Not really. How can argparser know that `cmd.py -s -t -p arg1 arg2 arg3` means "give all to all", instead of "-s gets no arguments, -t gets no arguments, -p gets 3 arguments"? Two different actions to perform but the argument list is the same.

Comment: @h4z3 this is what I am asking. How could I deal with such requirement?

Comment: @VijayShankerDubey Did you ever tried https://github.com/google/python-fire.

Comment: After parsing check if the `s` and `t` arguments are empty lists, and assign values from `p`.  You don't have to do everything in `argparse` itself.